# stopping Linux shell while it is resolving (i.e. expanding) wildcards

Tags: linux, shell, wildcard

In a typical Linux shell, you can use `Ctrl+c` to stop execution of a command. If you have started a run that uses wildcards (such as *) to find all files with a certain pattern, and if you have many files that need to be searched, it may take quite a long time for the shell to expand the wildcards to the actual file names. In the mean time Ctrl+c does not stop shell. Shell continues with resolving the wildcards. The Ctrl+c takes effect only after shell resolves the wildcard, and that can quite a bit of time.

Is there a way to stop the shell while it is trying to expand the wildcard?

This is tested on `GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Comment: You could always background it and then just kill the process...

Comment: Report this as a bug to the maintainers of whichever shell this is.  It *should* field `SIGINT` (or detect control-C, if it's put the terminal in raw mode) and abort the wildcard expansion.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Bash 4.2.24(1). Ctrl-c swiftly kills `echo **/*` as it's trashing the disk.

Comment: In that case it might just be because of my Bash version. I updated my question to reflect the version.

Answer (score 2):

If the shell seems to be taking inordinately long to expand wildcards, you most likely have one of these going on:

1. You are doing something like `*/*/*/*/*/*` - solution: don't do that; find a way to break down what you are doing into smaller bits, or at least process it more efficiently
2. You have a ridiculously large number of files in a directory - solution: don't do that; having too many files in a directory is a well known performance killer on many file systems (although some deal with it better than others)
3. Your file system is either a network file system (NFS, Samba/CIFS, sshfs, etc...) on a network link that is somewhat slow, or on a slow physical medium like a CD/DVD or something. Not much to do here except match fewer files at once, or wait it out.
4. Your file system is normally fast, but it's on an aging hard drive that is starting to have read/write errors resulting in trying to relocate sectors, which can look like extensive timeouts. Check your system logs for scary disk messages, and if this is the case, buy a new disk and move your data to it yesterday.
5. There are probably others...

In the meantime, other suggestions/comments/answers point to the ability to kill your shell if it appears hung.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could kill the process. `Ctrl-z` to stop, `ps aux | grep processname`, to get the process id, then `kill processid`.

Comment: `Ctrl-z` does not seem to work either when this happens. So, I cannot even stop it.